# Cambiar la tonalidad de los pixeles de una imagen RGB

Tags: imagen, matlab

estoy resolviendo el siguiente ejercicio de tratamiento de imágenes en matlab.

El ejercicio consiste en cambiar la tonalidad ciertos pixeles de una imagen RGB, en cualquiera de sus espectros, en este caso elegí el espectro ROJO. Únicamente se deberá cambiar la tonalidad de los pixeles en donde la tonalidad del pixel tenga un valor cero, osea de color oscuro. Hasta el momento he desarrollado el siguiente código, pero cambia toda la tonalidad de la imagen.

```
clc
close all
clear all
img = imread('luigi3.jpg');
imgR = img(:,:,1);
imgG = img(:,:,2);
imgB = img(:,:,3);
subplot(2,3,1);
imshow(imgR);
subplot(2,3,2);
imshow(imgG);
subplot(2,3,3);
imshow(imgB);
vectorR=find(imgR == 0);
value=size(vectorR,1);
for i=1:1:value
imgFinal = imgR(vectorR(i))+150;
end
subplot(2,3,4);
imshow(imgFinal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ten en cuenta que imgFinal la estás creando únicamente con los rojos de la imagen. Tendrías que juntar tu imgFinal con imgG e imgB y así crear una nueva imagen con los nuevos rojos:

```
I(:,:,1) = imgR(vectorR(i))+150;
I(:,:,2) = imgG
I(:,:,3) = imgB
```

En el caso que no quisieras ni verdes ni azules, I(:,:,2) e I(:,:,3) los tendrías que poner a 0 o a 1, dependiendo lo que quieras conseguir.

No estoy seguro si soluciona tu duda